# Building a docker image differently for test and release

Tags: docker, dockerfile

We have a tool we build into a docker image to run via Wine.

For testing the last line of our Dockerfile runs the application like this:

```
# Run application
ENTRYPOINT ["wine", "/app/OurApp.exe"]
```

This allows us to run test data thru it via:

```
echo %TEST_JSON% | docker run -i -a stdin -a stdout OurApp
```

For deployment the docker image is wrapped into a larger image that then runs the app. In order for it to work correctly when deployed I have to comment out the ENTRYPOINT line from the Dockerfile.

I'm not very familiar with Docker (I inherited this project) but assume their might be a better way to deal with Test / Deploy configurations. What would you suggest?

Comment: The standard advice is to use an identical image in all environments.  If you find yourself frequently needing to change the `ENTRYPOINT`, `CMD` is easier to override in a `docker run` command and you may be able to just change from one directive to the other.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I got it working by removing the `ENTRYPOINT` from the Dockerfile and setting it on the `docker run` command line.